# Print MySQL queries results with PHP in HTML pages

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple `MySQL query`: `SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM my_table`

How to `print results (in html pages)` with PHP in a preexisting DB connection?
Sorry for this stupid answer, I'm just learning PHP :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(column_name) AS count FROM my_table";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo "<p>" . $result['count'] . "</p>";
```

Should do the job.

Note: I used `AS count` in order to access it easier in the associative array.

Answer (score 0):

simplistically

```
<?
//Connect to the database
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(column_name) as total FROM my_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row['total'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(column_name) AS count FROM my_table");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo '<p>'. $result['count'] .'</p>';
```